# PHP mongoDb connection

Tags: php, mongodb

I am getting the below error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Client" not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\Project\index.php on line 3

I have installed the mongo db driver but when i run the php info i don't see the mongoDb section in it.
I am using 8.11.27 version of php and 8.1 version of mongodb dll driver.

I was trying to connect it with the mongDb data base and have followed all the steps from adding the file in ext folder to editing the .ini file.

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551